# Regarding notifying a particular thread deleibrately

Tags: java

I have developed the below java code ..

```
   class ThreadB extends Thread {
public  int totals;

 public void run() {
     synchronized(this) {
     for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
      totals += i;
      }
      notify(); //want to notify only thread b2
      }
      }
     }
```

and the other class is...

```
        class ThreadA {
     public static void main(String [] args) {
     ThreadB b1 = new ThreadB();
     b.start();
ThreadB b2 = new ThreadB();
b2.start();
ThreadB b3 = new ThreadB();
b3.start();
ThreadB b4 = new ThreadB();
b4.start();

     synchronized(b) {
     try {
     System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
     b1.wait();
b2.wait(); //only b2 to be notified
b3.wait();
b4.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    System.out.println("Total is: " + b.totals);
     }
    }
    }
```

No please advise me that I want to notify only thread b2 and b2 only , how I would achieve this , since notify thread can pick up any one thread , but I want only b2, please advise.

Comment: I think it would help if you could explain why you are trying to do this. I am not sure if your code even compiles.

Comment: Yeah agree , please if possible could you correct in class Thread A ,so that all the threads are waitibg for thread b to complete, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the reference `b2` waits on to the class which runs the thread you want to do the notifying.

You have to `synchronized` on the object you are wait()ing on.

Comment: Hi Peter, Please if you can show in the code that wll help to grasp more clearer ,thanks a lot